# Getting type of second param of a method

Tags: typescript

Using webext-bridge I can define my listeners like

// shims.d.ts

```
declare module 'webext-bridge' {
  export interface ProtocolMap {
    // define message protocol types
    // see https://github.com/antfu/webext-bridge#type-safe-protocols
    'event-name': { helloMessage: string };
  }
}
```

// code

```
onMessage('event-name', (message) => {
    // do something strict way
    console.log(message.data.helloMessage); // no ts error
});
```

How I can define the method for second param like

```
function onEventName(message: /* How to get message type dynamically here? */) {
    console.log(message.data.helloMessage); // ts not able to get type here
}
onMessage('event-name', onEventName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be defined as:

```js
import { onMessage, ProtocolMap, IBridgeMessage } from 'webext-bridge'

function onEventName(message: IBridgeMessage<ProtocolMap['event-name']>) {
    console.log(message.data.helloMessage);
}
onMessage('event-name', onEventName);
```

[TS play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhAdgWQKYGcsEMDmGANHAApQQwQDGEANmrmCQJIBCUwAJoZjgRjgBfOADMKIOAHIA7hgBGGAB4wAtPM48MUgLAAofVwzU6uKIJAQuAVzqDZC5Wo3dCUxPrhe4yyLDjAKDAYUKK41ILklDT0jGAeet5JcAD0KXBGooEW2HiEcGAUVLR0cDAAnmDYnsleaXBYGIIAFjAwYFgAXGn4wDDN1vIAdLQgKbhBotYpcooq6pqEAMQVVap4ohiqhdElWDW1UhgAbhhBqii4INqdiHDNGHR0EHx5GLdYMJwo+MIA3AdhPp9EJgXpUK8BAAKI6nc6Xa5SEhQ678QgASjgAF4AHwJJL1LgQBoQa79QK-T6cajwGS4cqA2goLD0DBDZ74FG5ARDLi4GC4IYPJ4vbkYv6pdIoYkwLA+KAUKAg9EAgxqqYoGnAVDIFAAUThMAAclcMFy0e84OxFhhIYQADxRYqxJgAbVhZzUCO0AF0cZiEIzUCy7OyIJzUW9efzBcLnnaMCrJWU5dL4Lh5HYysTCPBVi0QhgQfoIWKzR74aakbqDZ6TdcVfogA)

Comment: can we also set the return type of the method?

Comment: it would be `void` since the TS isn't "complaining", it would mean that if it returns anything it won't be used

Comment: see this method onMessage('event-with-return'..., https://shorturl.at/sINOZ it complains if the return type is not correct.

Comment: @coure2011 I stand corrected, the return type should be `void | Promise<void>`